# Assign class variables empty string and list them in order of definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to initialize a bunch of variables such that I can also print an array of those variables in the order they were defined. I thought using an `enum class` might help with that... so I took this working code that I cobbled together...

```
from enum import Enum
class all_vars(Enum):
    var1='1'
    var2='2'
    var3='3'
    var4='4'

var_array=[]
for items in all_vars:
    var_array.append(items.name)

print(var_array) --outputs ['var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4']
```

And modified it to my use case--**initialize with empty string instead**

```
from enum import Enum
class all_vars(Enum):
    var1=''
    var2=''
    var3=''
    var4=''

var_array=[]
for items in all_vars:
    var_array.append(items.name)
    
print(var_array) --outputs ['var1']  --need all the variables here
```

How do I make it include all the variables in the array in the second case. If `Enum` isn't the way to go about this, I'm open to other alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing items in the `Enum` in this way will only give you the first instance of each unique value you stored. However, the `Enum` does know what those other values are and that it has them, they are stored in the `_member_map_` of the `Enum`. So you can access them like so:

```
var_array=[]
for item in all_vars._member_map_:
    var_array.append(item)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted